# shebang line - multiple allowed interpreters by order

Tags: python, shebang

I've got a script that requires python3.7 or above.
I've got multiple systems each with different python versions. all of them have either python3.7 or python3.8 but just "python3" can also be python3.6.

Is there a way to make a shebang line take either python3.7 or python3.8? and fail if none exist of course.

I tried a billion of options and nothing works. I was hoping for something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.7 || /usr/bin/python3.8
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.7
#!/usr/bin/python3.8
```

but nada.. I also couldn't google it up which kinda makes me sad but who knows maybe the answer is there somewhere and I'm just using a bizarre jargon

these are not systems I can change defaults on and installing python3.7 on each such setup is sadly not an option (would make life awesome).

Comment: Could you just use `#!/usr/bin/python3` and then check if it is 3.7 or above with `sys.version_info.major == 3 and sys.version_info.minor >= 7`?

Comment: that is just like making my own wrapper script with bash and then calling the appropriate python from with it.. will save me from having to copy this code to every such script I have. but is there no better generic way to do it?

Comment: I was more thinking of making the first part of your python scrip check if it is running with the correct version, and if not, then fail.

Comment: But what will be in the shebang? python3 is python3.6 on some systems but they for sure have python3.7 or python3.8

Comment: Do you mean that they have python 3.6 as python3 and also some newer python at other, more or less known path.  I understood you as they they have either supported version as python3 or not at all. Then I think you are back to wrapper script “testing” for known locations.

Comment: yup that's what I mean :(

Answer (score 0):

The shebang simply needs to point to an actual executable.

*That executable* can be one which finds a suitable version of the Python interpreter; see for example the `py` tool which was popular on Windows for a long time but which is now also being made available on <del>real computers.</del> other platforms.

Ultimately, something somewhere needs to be on the user's `PATH`, which obviously you will not always have control over. If you are targeting unsophisticated users, perhaps look into providing your code in a compiled executable, a prepackaged Docker image, or something vaguely like that.